# Can't avoid interpolation of UV : " 'flat' : Illegal use of reserved word "

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, webgl2

I want to made that UV are not interpolated, so I can get the exact pixel (As a beginner I see this from [that video](https://youtu.be/oKbCaj1J6EI?t=4052)). **Why using 'flat' gives an error?**

If I past `flat` before varying of `Uv` (I named it `vUv`):

```
flat varying vec2 vUv;
```

I get that **errors from VS Code extentsion** [WebGL GLSL Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=raczzalan.webgl-glsl-editor):

```
'flat' : Reserved word. 
'flat' : not supported for this version or the enabled extensions
```

And that **error from Three.js** in console:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: Shader Error 0 - VALIDATE_STATUS false

Material Name: 
Material Type: RawShaderMaterial

Program Info Log: Vertex shader is not compiled.

VERTEX

ERROR: 0:14: 'flat' : Illegal use of reserved word

  9: attribute vec2 uv;
  10: 
  11: varying float time;
  12: varying vec3 vPostion;
  13: varying vec3 vNormal;
> 14: flat varying vec2 vUv;
  15: 
  16: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
```

The **answer why it gives an error** might be:

> I think 'flat' is not supported by the version of GLSL used in WebGL.

From [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40101324/22046951) on the same error.

But the answer says how to get normalized normals (I want UV instead). I also didn't understand where to get `vertex_view_space` (position of object from camera perspective as I understood) in Three.js, but it doesn't matter as it for calculating vertex normals. I might be wrong.

I find how to stop interpolation of color - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882689/22046951), but I need UV.

**P.S.**

[This site](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl1-to-webgl2.html) helped me move from GLSL1 to GLSL3

Comment: What version of three.js are you using? Ensure you're using a `WebGL2RenderingContext` for support, and your shader should have `#version 300 es` at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flat` qualifier is not supported in GLSL ES 1.00 ([OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf)). You have to use a shader with `#version 300 es` (see [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00 Specification](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.pdf#page=44&zoom=100,153,144)). In three.js this can be achieved by setting the property `.glslVersion` to `THREE.GLSL3` in the [`ShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial):

```js
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
   glslVersion: THREE.GLSL3,
   // [...]
} );
```

Note that this is of course only possible with a WebGL 2.0 context ( however, this is the default in three.js if possible)

If you do not use a three.js `ShaderMaterial` you have to put the version information in the first line of the shader

```c
#version 300 es
```

Additionally you need to migrate the shader code from GLSL ES 1.00 to GLSL ES 3.00.